# Databricks notebook getting stuck

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a DBx notebook using which I extract data from multiple tables of RedShift into a Spark df. After combining data, I load the same df into another Redshift table. This query was running fine and taking less than 15 minutes to finish in last few months. Unfortunately, from today, this query is just so long that I ultimately end up killing the process. During every execution, its getting stuck here [image: databricks error]

Does anyone have any ideas how can I troubleshoot? I restarted cluster, detached and re-attached my notebook, changed date range in query, but nothing is working.
TIA

Comment: Any thoughts guys..help pls

Comment: Open up the Spark UI and see what the final stage is.  You are probably bottlenecked there.